# Why the complex number system is not an ordered field

Tags: complex-analysis, field-theory

In high school, we are taught that we do not have $2i < 3i$, i.e., the complex number system is not an ordered field.

(Real number, for example, is an ordered field. For example, $2 < 3$).

**Why?**

My comment to this is because in the complex corrdinate, in $Re-Im$ coordinate, the concept of complex number is somewhat a rotation around the origin.

Comment: That's more or less right. On the number line, which of two numbers is furthest to the right is a well-behaved notion (especially with respect to multiplication). In the complex plane, it isn't so well-behaved anymore. Not even the notion of positive and negative has a well-established generalization.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184547/total-order-on-complex-numbers.

Comment: see my answer to: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264203/complex-number-inqualities/1264307#1264307

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an order in your field, you will want your order to be compatible with the field operations.  This basically means that the sum and product of positives should be positive; and it has many consequences. One of them is that if $a <b $, then  $b-a>0$. So if $2i <3i $, 
$$
0 <3i-2i=i.
$$
Now $i $ is positive, and by squaring we get $-1>0$. Probably not what you intended.

Comment: See Henning Makholm's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184547/total-order-on-complex-numbers).